# How to decrypt password with the salt and key

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have a Wordpress site, I can get the DB

```
define( 'AUTH_KEY',          ']=qLUfn<#Ud(0UC:v~euV7P3:rNUJrh~sYy/1C>#?]#;I*,4oDh9.D]+u88K2g}D' );

define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',   'Mj2H!fBT^~vT]oRju,S.4{R[8IWI#rCe g>%f}#1)B8eDG1GIyGnf8}Sy3eJ(tB+' );

define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',     'BER}=[+(:[lxKTMM$A#M}v^Vd?`e}V}eUWVC.KFHRj]oNmX1#TwNLbtP}</evTp0' );

define( 'NONCE_KEY',         '@$s}upz2;spO #t;)tOvjQO;PJm>%-7;%w%587CtjcPTm<u(18/;a[<]&I#hOzpv' );

define( 'AUTH_SALT',         '}:65Uv=&-urr:3XPbZ6H]#*.*rI|}Qa!20G/)_86#<7jh0;K.Ry[o$3q!5EDg.J)' );

define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT',  '3JS:|_nh)@}oybO,/Gr%2`a&4h`c Nr%~*zzB7fVlzjcoRJP@%{3HAMJ&BDwb+cZ' );

define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',    's nK.Xi;lQ:]elQh1y}|E,1fC<DwxlCKfF7OBD/XcZ!?*vDinn3#bz^7z*P2&/Rv' );

define( 'NONCE_SALT',        '_rSf1,h[h@y5|/aR>PAdL:uN=?9ouuFn YAf]!|LAI9+#r^g1@ZuRs8-I9#OVEuk' );

define( 'WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', 'IM2Uj~pFoIpg$<~.}/Ys/|tpB~9WnK qK,Z}5h[EC!;y#=N+<7J4XS$^$@.4f;t!' );
```

And here the password from phpadmin

```
$P$BdHJkXeIo6itat/H7VvNPx0jte74hT0
```

I want to know how to decrypt the password. I am the admin and I know I can change it.

Comment: forget the old, get the [new](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_password/) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t decrypt it because it’s not encrypted — it’s hashed with MD5 algorithm with salt. You can try to brute force it but it may take years before you succeed. [Cracking WordPress Passwords with Hashcat](https://blog.wpsec.com/cracking-wordpress-passwords-with-hashcat/).